# How to create a Stripe object only if it does not yet exist

Tags: php, stripe-payments

My checkout flow requires a PaymentIntent to be created only once per order. Thus its ID is basically the same as the order ID. The API documentation is a bit unclear regarding the behavior of create() and retrieve(). So, what is the correct way to do this?

This best reflects the intention but doesn't work:

```
$stripeIntentId = "pi_{$order->id}";
if (!$stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve($stripeIntentId, []))
{
    $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
        'id' => $stripeIntentId,
        'amount' => $payAmount,
        'currency' => $payCurrency,
        'description' => $payDescription,
        'automatic_payment_methods' => ['enabled' => true],
        'metadata' => ['order_id' => $order->id],
    ]);
}
```

So I'm now pondering this, although this seems a bit overkill for the purpose.

```
$stripeIntentId = "pi_{$order->id}";
try
{
    $stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve($stripeIntentId, []);
} catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
        'id' => $stripeIntentId,
        'amount' => $payAmount,
        'currency' => $payCurrency,
        'description' => $payDescription,
        'automatic_payment_methods' => ['enabled' => true],
        'metadata' => ['order_id' => $order->id],
    ]);
}
```

I could not yet test this, but wonder if there is a more elegant way to do this. Exception handling is clearly not the best tool here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't manipulate Stripe object IDs (except Coupons, for some reason).

The Payment Intent ID is going to be randomly generated once you create it.

What you should do is use metadata, like this:

```
//Check for existing payments with metadata
$stripe->paymentIntents->search([
  'query' => 'metadata[\'order_id\']:\'6735\'',
]);  
//If none, proceed to creation
$stripe->paymentIntents->create([
        'amount' => $payAmount,
        'currency' => $payCurrency,
        'description' => $payDescription,
        'automatic_payment_methods' => ['enabled' => true],
        'metadata' => ['order_id' => '6735'],
    ]);
```

Comment: I already suspected the IDs to be read-only, thanks for confirming this. The search() method will do exacty what I need, although it's probably not very efficient with large databases. Your suggestion answers the question and @bismarck pointed me to a good alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend just updating your database at the time of PaymentIntent creation. So, for a return customer/order, you query your database to check if a a PaymentIntent ID associated to the order ID, otherwise you create one. As you noted, you shouldn't use the Stripe API to help you determine whether the PaymentIntent exists or not.

Comment: @Lucky2501 answered the question, but your suggestion points to a much better way of organizing our data. Thanks!